# Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 6 but received input with shape (None, 1)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am currently writing a machine learning regression program in Python using Keras.

I get incompatible input shape error... Please help!

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras import layers
from keras import models
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


data = pd.read_csv('path/to/csv', sep=',')
y = data.points

X = data.copy(deep=True)
X.drop(columns=['points'], inplace=True)

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense_1', input_shape=(6,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense_2'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, name='output'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])

results = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test) 
print("Results: ", results)

arr = np.array([0.04, 0.01, 0.35, 0, 0, 0.001])
prediction = model.predict(arr.reshape(-1, 1))
print(prediction)
```

Here is a dataset sample:

[dataset sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsI2J.png)

The *points* column is the one to be predicted.

In the `predict` line, I get this error

```
 ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 6 but received input with shape (None, 1)
```

Comment: Change your predict line like this: `prediction = model.predict(arr.reshape((1,6))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model expects first dimension as a batch, and the other dimensions based on your input model. So, if your model input is `(6,)`, and you want to predict one sample, you should pass a data with shape `(1,6)`.

So, change your predict line like this:

```
prediction = model.predict(arr.reshape((1,-1)))
```